# Error:Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

So i am working on a simple javascript widget and i started up by followinf [this](http://alexmarandon.com/articles/web_widget_jquery/) tutorial. I am loading jquery dynamically like below:

```
if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '2.1.4') {
```

UPDATE, Here is how i'm loading jQuery

```
var script_tag = document.createElement('script');
        script_tag.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        script_tag.setAttribute("src",
            "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js");
 document.documentElement).appendChild(script_tag);        

//Once loaded load other javascripts
if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded') {

    scriptLoadHandler();

  }
}
```

Following is my `scriptLoadHandler` function:

```
function scriptLoadHandler() {

        // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
        // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict(true);
        // Call our main function
        main();
    }
```

Now, in the main method i'm trying to load Bootstrap js like this:

```
    function main() {

        console.log("undefined" == typeof jQuery);

        var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
        var js = document.createElement("script");
        js.type = "text/javascript";
        js.src = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js";
        head.appendChild(js);

    }
```

But it's still giving me above error even though the order in which they load is correct and when i check console log it gives me `false` which means jQuery is defined.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79519/discussion-on-question-by-hussain-errorbootstraps-javascript-requires-jquery).

Answer (score 0):

Check  if JQuery is loaded before of bootstrap loading request. If JQuery is not already loaded bootstrap can not be loaded

Comment: i did check that and in the document response the jquery script lies above the bootstrap script.

Answer (score 0):

`//Load jquery here`

You're not loading jQuery there.

You should either create a `SCRIPT` element in the DOM before this script with src your jQuery lib location, or load it dynamically after the line I've quoted (i.e. create the script tag, set the src to your jquery lib relative or absolute URL/URI, add the onloaded event handler to execute `scriptLoadHandler` and eventually append the new script to the DOM)

Easiest way is to load the script via a script TAG BEFORE the script you're using.

EDIT: after more information by OP, here is the solution:

1. check for the version of jQuery: if it's not the one you want, load it.
2. After you've loaded the jQuery version you need (or if it's already loaded), load Bootstrap.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1h6emjwu/2/

```
    function loadScript(src, callback) {
        var js = document.createElement('script');
        js.src = src;
        js.type = 'text/javascript';

        if (typeof callback === 'function') {
            js.addEventListener('load', callback);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(js);
    }

    var myScript = function () {
        //alert(window.jQuery.fn.jquery);
        alert($.fn.modal ? 'Bootstrap loaded' : 'Bootstrap not loaded');
    }

    if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '2.1.4') {
        window.oldJQuery = window.jQuery; // so that you can return back whenever you want
        loadScript('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js', function () {
            loadScript('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', myScript);
        });
    } else {
        loadScript('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', myScript);
    }
```

Comment: OP didn't post all relevant code as i can see it because then `if (this.readyState == 'complete' || this.readyState == 'loaded')` wouldn't make sense

Comment: Possibly, yes, but again I think that dynamically loading jQuery in a bootstrap-themed template is a non-sense. I'd opt for loading jQuery from the CDN directly...

Comment: Ya doesn't really make sense in website context but maybe OP is using some user script and want absolutely sure to load specific jQuery 2.1.4 version and so want to override any other version loaded or load it if jQuery not already included, but i'm just guessing, unclear question somehow. **EDIT:** forget about user script, that's for a widget so make sense indeed: `So i am working on a simple javascript widget`

Comment: guys when i said `//Load jquery here` i meant i have loaded it, i just didnt post the details. let me just update the post if thats what you want

Comment: @hussain, can't you simply add `<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>` before you call your code?

Comment: Add that tag and then the following: `<script>console.log(jQuery === undefined ? 'jQuery failed loading' : 'jQuery is loaded');</script>` (and eventually the rest of the code)